# How do I pass and then access an object inside a directive template (directive uses isolate scope)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a collection of navBarItems and am currently presenting them like this:

```
 <a data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" ng-show="navBarItems['search'].show" ng-click="navBarItems['search'].click()" data-icon="{{navBarItems['search'].icon}}">{{navBarItems['search'].title}}</a>
```

I'm repeating this code and just changing the 'type', so I'd like to create a directive with a template and call it like this:

```
<navBarItem type="search"></navBarItem>
```

I've tried passing the attribute to an isolated scope but then can't get to the navBarItems once in the directive.

Comment: If you are creating an isolate scope, you'll also have to pass navBarItems via another attribute.  Use `=` in the isolate scope definition to pass the object.

Comment: Simple as that; been staring at that for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, since an isolate scope is being used/created, any other data that the isolate scope requires will need to be passed to the directive via additional attributes on the same element.  In this case `navBarItems` needs to be specified:

```
<navBarItem type="search" items="navBarItems"></navBarItem>
```

Since `navBarItems` is an object (not a string), the `=` syntax should be used in the isolate scope definition:

```
scope: { items:'=',  ... },
```